# Beginner videos

Tags: wireframe

I downloaded Blender about a week ago and I still can't get past "import the picture". I've watched every video I can find, but it doesn't work. Probably something really simple but I'm stumped. Tried svg, bmp, jpeg and png formats to no avail. What I want to do is import picture and turn it to wireframe for laser engraving on acrylic. (My designs) Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Enzo

Comment: "import picture and turn it to wireframe" could you better describe what are you doing? What is wireframe in this case? Is it related to [wireframe shading mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html) or [wireframe modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html)? Do you want to model an object according to the picture or rather have a picture as object to be rendered? Use [edit] link to edit your post and change title to something more descriptive as well

Comment: I think the wireframe modifier was what I was after, but I think I'm going to try Inkscape first. Thank you, appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

### First

First Of all , You must make a simple svg image ,I gonna make a simple star With **Inkscape** - Be sure that the Svg image doesn't have a fill Colour and a thin Stroke -.

[image]

After Saving your image , Open blender and from **File Menu** > **Import** > **svg**

[image]

Then Select your **SVG File** (It maybe small so it is better to scale it)

[image]

### Second

When the Svg is imported it is imported as a curve so it is very easy to make something follow it (By Using Follow Path in Constraints).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to input other graphics after this.

Comment: Curious..why will it not let me choose wireframe modifier for imported svg image?

Comment: Because it's a curve, not a mesh. Wireframe simply doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Blender probably isn't the best tool for this. You should try [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) instead.

But if you really want to use Blender, here's  how  you import the picture:

- Hit <kbd>7</kbd> on your numpad to go into top view, and then <kbd>5</kbd> on the numpad to go into orthographic mode (no perspective).

  - If you don't have a numpad, turn on Emulate Numpad in the preferences, then click the **Save User Settings** button.
- Drag the picture into the 3D View. This should set it as a background image.
- Edit away!

Comment: I have Inkscape also. Didn't know it would do that. I'll go there first. Thanks much!